# Recreating Folder Redirection user folders automatically

Tags: windows

I created a user `Test1` to see if my Folder Redirection is working fine. After creating it, I see that it is working without problems. I tested it also with a `Test2` user.

I deleted user `Test1` in AD and the Folder Redirection folder stored on the server.

I also completely deleted the profile from the local machine. I created user `Test1` again, on the local Machine the "Welcome-Screen" [reappeared] so the profile was deleted successfully before.

The problem is that the Folder-Redirection folders are not created automatically like the first time.

Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Can it possible because exisisting offline files?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you should delete your self answer and instead edit your original question. The Self Answer makes it appear that someone has started to help you already when in fact that is not the case.

Comment: How is folder redirection configured? Domain group policy or local group policy? (Or could you possibly be referring to the user's home folder property on their AD account?